# Unable to run cron job with standard user account

Tags: cron, solaris

The same job can be executed as root, but it can't execute as a standard user.
Is it permission problem or I need to change anything, I have no idea on it. 
Thanks

SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-30 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120

Command:

1) login as a root

2) crontab -l

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/date > /tmp/root.log
```

3) /tmp/root.log is here

---

1) login as a Non-root user

2) crontab -l

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/date > /tmp/non-root.log
```

3) /tmp/non-root.log is not here

Comment: You're not exactly overloading us with information. Which command? Does it work from the command line executed as non-root user? What did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry, i updated the command in there. Thanks

Comment: It probably has to do with the file `/tmp/output.log`. If this file already exists (because you tried it as root), it'll belong to root and you can't overwrite it.
Cleanup your `/tmp` directory first and try again

Comment: Yes, i tried to save on two separated files, but apparently the file didn't create

Comment: Does it work from the command line? Hence, as non-root user just enter `date > /tmp/non-root.log` from the shell. If the file isn't created, you'll have to check the permissions of `/tmp`, if it is, try to use the full qualified path within your cron file (like `/usr/bin/date`).

Comment: Yes, the command can be executed correctly with non-root user. I wonder it would be the cron problem itself

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/cron.d/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.d/cron.deny`?  If neither file exists, only `root` can run cron jobs.

Comment: I've added the non-root account into cron.allow, and also make sure that cron.deny is not contained this account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I finally found out the issue.

The reason is that non-root account is locked out, I think it maybe someone did many failure attempt which make this locked.

After I passwd -u "Account", the job can be run as expected. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

The following permissions are OK for the binary file `date`

```
-bash-3.2# ls -l /usr/bin/date
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        11056 Jan 22  2005 /usr/bin/date
-bash-3.2#
```

If the permissions are OK check your cron log on `/var/cron/log` file

```
-bash-3.2# tail /var/cron/log
<  root 24592 c Fri Oct 20 18:50:21 2017
>  CMD: /usr/bin/date > /tmp/non-root.log
>  user 25192 c Fri Oct 20 18:51:00 2017
<  user 25192 c Fri Oct 20 18:51:00 2017
>  CMD: /scripts/collectdata.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
>  root 25769 c Fri Oct 20 18:52:00 2017
<  root 25769 c Fri Oct 20 18:52:00 2017
>  CMD: /scripts/collectdata.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
>  root 26853 c Fri Oct 20 18:54:00 2017
<  root 26853 c Fri Oct 20 18:54:00 2017
-bash-3.2#
```